# Is this PHP/MySQL delete function secure?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-delete

I have a setup where I am deleting entries from a table.

It is based on the querystring of the URL which I'm thinking might be a bad way to start anyway.

So if the URL is:

`http://www.example.com/delete.php?id=123&ref=abc`

And the php in delete.php is as follows:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$ref=$_GET['ref'];

$con = mysql_connect("blahblah","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id=" . $id . " AND ref='" . $ref . "'");

mysql_close($con);
```

Is there a way to make this more secure... or is this indeed in any way secure at all??

**EDIT:**

OK, so based on the feedback I've taken a new approach.

list.php contains a set of radiobuttons for each entry in the table - as follows:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable");

echo "<form name='wer' id='wer' action='delete.php' method='post' >";

echo "<table border='1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='radio' name='test1' value='" . $row['id'] . "' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />";
echo "</form>";

mysql_close($con);
```

And delete.php looks like this:

```
function check_input($value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    return $value;
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$varID = check_input($_POST["id"]);

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$sql="DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN (" . $varID . ")";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);

header("Location: list.php");
```

Is this a better way to go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i make $_GET more secure.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682480/how-do-i-make-get-more-secure)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Deleting is an idempotent operation.

Comment: @Gumbo: I always thought that one shouldn't change a database on a `GET` request.

Comment: @Marcel one shouldn't delete stuff in a GET request. Because GET requests should not have significant side-effects. But it's still idempotent i.e. deleting twice has the same result as deleting once.

Comment: @Code: thanks, you're right, I stand corrected. It's not my best day, today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You have a  SQL injection vulnerability since you don't sanitize the GET parameters you put into your query. The attacker can use that to delete all elements in your table.
   The clean solution to this is using `prepared Statements`.
   The quick and dirty solution is putting them in quotation marks and running them through [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).
2. Even if you fix that part, if the attacker can guess a valid `id`/`ref` pair he can delete that entry.
3. If a parameter is an integer, then why don't you make its type integer too? Something like `$id=intval($_GET['id'])`

Comment: I thought that might be the case... but i'm not sure where to start looking to fix this vulnerability... any hints??

Comment: Use prepared statements. But I'm not familiar enough with php to tell you what API you need to use for that.

Comment: One can use prepared statements using [PDO](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @Marcel How does 0 being an invalid index affect the security of this? The attacker can already enter any valid integer.

Answer (score 5):

GET is considered a [safe method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.1) and should not have any side effects:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
> HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
> other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".

In your case your script might be vulnerable to [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). You should better use POST instead and consider some kind of authentication and authorization check before deleting.

Additionally, since you use the passed parameters unaudited and unmodified, you are also vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Note that using POST doesn't remove the CSRF vulnerability, it just makes it marginally harder to pull off.  Using nonces in your forms will protect against CSRF more thoroughly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250263/csrf-protection-by-storing-nonce-in-session-variable-and-form

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you should put these values into parameters instead of sticking them right into your SQL statement.  Right now you are vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack.  Here is a good article on how to parameterize your query, use a stored procedure, or validate the incoming statement.  This should greatly help your security:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query(sprintf("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id='%s' AND ref='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($id),mysql_real_escape_string($res)));
```